# Getting types of keys within dictionary/json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a JSON response that I'm looking to parse through. I'd like to get all of the keys that have a dictionary of values and are not just a string.

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "style": 7,
        "accessDate": "2017-06-16T12:52:18Z",
        "name": "Starbucks",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 40.767372,
            "longitude": -111.891367,
        },
        "abstract": {
            "type": 5
        }
    }
]
```

Basically I'd like to get a list of every key that has a dictionary (in this case, `location` and `abstract`). I tried using `type()` but this just returns a string because...obviously.

```
for key in myjson:
    print(type(key))
```

Is there an alternative to finding where these might exist within a json?

Comment: Do you use `json.load` from the build-in json parser? You shouldn't need to write your own. Now the type should really be dict for those that are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isinstance` to see if a value is an instance of a class

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isinstance`

**Ex:**

```
j = [
    {
        "style": 7,
        "accessDate": "2017-06-16T12:52:18Z",
        "name": "Starbucks",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 40.767372,
            "longitude": -111.891367,
        },
        "abstract": {
            "type": 5
        }
    }
]

for i in j:
    for key, value in i.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            print(key)
```

**Output:**

```
location
abstract
```